# Get files from a directory and segregate it with name in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement to be automated using VB macro where i have to take a set of xls files from a specific folder and convert them to csv then segregate it according to the file name like All File name has benifit will be put into a new folder called benifit and all Funds will be put into a folder called funds ( we have to create a folder in some path ) .

I have code to conver the xls to csv by hardcoding the path but i dont know how to segregate it wrt name .

Any ideas or code would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

<>

The below code gets the input path where the files are present and convert them to csv to the output path all at once

Now I want to Enhance this code to

```
 Sub ConvertXLStoCSVNoRules(mySourcePath, myKeywordPath)
Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set strInputFolder = MyObject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)
Set strOutputFolder = MyObject.GetFolder(myKeywordPath)
strInputFolder = strInputFolder & "\"
strOutputFolder = strOutputFolder & "\"
strXLSFile = Dir(strInputFolder & "*.xls*")
counter = 0
row = 13
Worksheets("Main").Cells(row, 1).Value = "Files processed at " & Now
row = row + 1
On Error Resume Next
Do While strXLSFile <> ""
    counter = counter + 1
    row = row + 1

    'strCSVFile = Left(strXLSFile, InStrRev(strXLSFile, ".")) & "csv"
    strCSVFile = Left(strXLSFile, 4) & " SL" & ".csv"

    'Add into the first sheet for recording purpose
    Worksheets("Main").Cells(row, 1).Value = strXLSFile

    Workbooks.Open strInputFolder & strXLSFile
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strOutputFolder & strCSVFile, xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    strXLSFile = Dir

Loop
    'MsgBox ("Files completed " & counter)
    row = row + 1
    Worksheets("Main").Cells(row, 1).Value = "Files completed " & counter & " at " & Now
End Sub
```

- Categorize the files with respect to the file names in new folder
- for eg There are 100 files in a folder the above code will convert it to csv and put it in a given path

But i want to enhance it has The code should seperate the csv or xls files from the file names like all files has benifits in the file name should be come to a new folder called benifits

All files with funds should come into a new folder called funds , it can happen before the csv conversion or even after ,

Please suggest me the best way

Comment: To get any help show the code you already have.

Comment: Can you break your first paragraph into multiple sentences? It's very hard to understand as is.

Comment: The below code gets the input path where the files are present and convert them to csv to the output path all at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just change the output filename based on the input filename with code similar to the following:

```
Dim Index As Integer
Dim outputFolder As String
Dim specialFolders(1 To 2) As String

specialFolders(1) = "funds"
specialFolders(2) = "benifit"

outputFolder = strOutputFolder
For Index = LBound(specialFolders) To UBound(specialFolders)
    If InStr(1, strCSVFile, specialFolders(Index), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        outputFolder = outputFolder & specialFolders(Index) & "\"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs outputFolder & strCSVFile, xlCSV
```